# get Solana transaction status using Rust

Tags: solana-program, rust, error

I'm trying to get Solana transaction status using Rust. You can get the transaction status using explorer.solana.com, but I want to get it via code.

I tried to use the get_signature_status function in the Rust SDK.
The function above expect a signature object.

So I tried using it:

```
let sig_s = String::from("...");
let sig: Signature = Signature(sig_s.as_bytes());
let stat = self.client.get_signature_status(&sig);
println!("{:?}", stat);
```

But I getting error of: "constructor is not visible here due to private fields"

I'm trying to understand if there is another way to create Signature object, I guess there should be a way to create Signature object and get its status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using outdated version of solana docs. In the latest version, Signature implements FromStr so you can do the following:

```
let sig = Signature::from_str(sig_s).unwrap();
```

And that'll get you a signature you can use.

See https://docs.rs/solana-sdk for the latest version.